# Can't find a table using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to using Beautiful soup for web scraping. I'm trying to extract a table from https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/search/browse?brwse=cond_alpha_all but it's not working and I can't seem to find why. Here's what I did

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/search/browse?brwse=cond_alpha_all"

r = requests.get(url) #### recupérer le html
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content) #### parser ce txt en html
table = soup.find("table",{"id":"theDataTable","class":"display dataTable no-footer"})
```

it can't find the table ! why is that?

Comment: read the source code of the page (`ctrl+u` for firefox) you'll find the data in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @AkramHECINI You should mark one of the answers as accepted (if it fixed your problem) so other users can benefit from the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's within the `<script>` tag. Need to pull it out and parse it.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/search/browse?brwse=cond_alpha_all'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'var tableData1' in str(script):
        jsonStr = str(script)
        jsonStr = str(script).split('var tableData1 = ', 1)[-1]
        
        while True:
            try:
                jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
                break
            except:
                jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';', 1)[0]
        


df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData)
df.columns = ['Conditions','Studies']
df['Conditions'] = [BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser').text for x in list(df['Conditions'])]
```

**Output:**

```
Conditions Studies
0                                ACTH Syndrome, Ectopic       8
1                      ACTH-Secreting Pituitary Adenoma      62
2     ACTH-independent Macronodular Adrenal Hyperplasia       2
3                              ADCY5-related Dyskinesia       2
4                                         ADNP Syndrome       2
                                                ...     ...
5653                46, XX Disorders of Sex Development      58
5654                                    47 XXX Syndrome       2
5655                                   47, XYY Syndrome       3
5656                            5-Nucleotidase Syndrome       1
5657                                       5q- Syndrome       1

[5658 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/search/browse?brwse=cond_alpha_all"

r = requests.get(url) # Fetch the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") # Parse the page in HTML
table = soup.find("table", { "id": "theDataTable", "class": ["display", "dataTable", "no-footer"]})
```

What is not working in your code is the `soup.find(...)` statement, where you wrote `"class":"display dataTable no-footer"` instead of `"class": ["display", "dataTable", "no-footer"]`.

**BeautifulSoup requires you to pass the several classes as an array of strings, not as a single string.**

You will notice that I also added `"html.parser"` as second argument in the `BeautifulSoup(...)` constructor. While this is not mandatory, it is better to put it to avoid the `GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified,[...]` warning that Python could throw.

You can find the documentation of the libraries here:

- [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
- [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)